# ValidationExpersion is not a valid attribute of element 'RegularExpressionValidator'

Tags: asp.net

I have this problem: when I'm trying to insert a valid value into `Email` textbox, I get that this value that was inserted, is invalid. This is how i wrote part of the code in the aspx file:

```
ValidationExpersion="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\ w +([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

This is the message that refer to above code:

> Attribute 'ValidationExpersion' is not a valid attribute of element 'RegularExpressionValidator'.

I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have a typo in the code (as you do in the question.)  The attribute is `ValidationExpression` so make sure it matches exactly.

EDIT:

Just to make things a little more clear here is the code you pasted and the correct version:

```
ValidationExpersion="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\ w +([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\ w +([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
```

You spelled ValidationExpression wrong.  When programming you have to be accurate with spelling, especially when using built in attributes like ValidationExpression.  If you are off  by even one letter then the "compiler" will think it's something else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, can you specified more. You mean that maybe i didnt insert correct value into Email textbox?